# Can't run headless Firefox by selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, firefox, selenium-webdriver, headless

I want to use headless Firefox from Selenium WebDriver, but it failed with a unknown error.

```
$ bundle exec pry
> require 'selenium-webdriver'
> Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1
from stack backtrace:
```

This is my environment. What can I do to remove the error?

```
$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 56.0
$ less Gemfile.lock | grep selenium
selenium-webdriver (3.6.0)
$ geckodriver --version
geckodriver 0.19.0
```

Comment: no solution since?